# Why does my kernel menuconfig look corrupted?

Tags: kernel, buildroot

I've been using buildroot 2018.02.1 to compile a kernel for an embedded system. The kernel menuconfig used to render just fine, but at some point it stopped being rendered correctly and looks like this:

[image: Kernel menuconfig]

I've tried completely deleting the buildroot folder and starting again, but to no avail. The buildroot menuconfig renders OK, other kernel menuconfigs that I have also seem to render OK, e.g.:

[image: Buildroot menuconfig]

I've tried running `export NCURSES_NO_UTF8_ACS=1` before launching the kernel menuconfig, but it doesn't have any effect (although it does affect the buildroot menuconfig).

My locale settings are:

```
$ locale
LANG=en_GB.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=en_GB:en
LC_CTYPE="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC=en_GB.UTF-8
LC_TIME=en_GB.UTF-8
LC_COLLATE="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY=en_GB.UTF-8
LC_MESSAGES="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER=en_GB.UTF-8
LC_NAME=en_GB.UTF-8
LC_ADDRESS=en_GB.UTF-8
LC_TELEPHONE=en_GB.UTF-8
LC_MEASUREMENT=en_GB.UTF-8
LC_IDENTIFICATION=en_GB.UTF-8
LC_ALL=
```

Any thoughts?

**EDIT:** If I manually go into the output/build/linux-XXX folder and call `ARCH=arm make menuconfig`, it displays fine. The problem appears to be related to how Buildroot is calling menuconfig.

Comment: Have you try to exec it on this way: `LAND=C make menuconfig`

Comment: @RomeoNinov Thanks for the suggestion - after doing some more experimenting, this appears to be an issue with how Buildroot is calling menuconfig. If I manually go into the linux folder and call menuconfig myself, it works fine.

Comment: Good that you found the source of the problem. I suggest you post it as an answer and accept it.

Answer (score 2):

I had exactly a similar problem: menuconfig, linux-menuconfig rendered ok, but uboot-menuconfig rendered incorrectly.

At first, check if you have installed ncursesw library on your host machine:

```
pkg-config --cflags ncursesw
```

On Debian I didn't have that library and i had to install it:

```
sudo apt-get install libncursesw5-dev
```

I hope this may help somebody.

Comment: Thanks.  On my Ubuntu 22.04 installation, I didn't have the `pkg-config` command.  When I installed `pkgconf` to add it, `make menuconfig` started looking correct.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the LDFLAGS in linux.mk

```
LINUX_MAKE_FLAGS = \
-       HOSTCC="$(HOSTCC) $(HOST_CFLAGS) $(HOST_LDFLAGS)" \
+       HOSTCC="$(HOSTCC) $(HOST_CFLAGS)" \
        ARCH=$(KERNEL_ARCH) \
        INSTALL_MOD_PATH=$(TARGET_DIR) \
        CROSS_COMPILE="$(TARGET_CROSS)" \
```